# How to add ?ref to url from other websites?

Tags: php, html, url, referer

I'm curious in knowing how websites manage to add ?ref to their URLS when being referred from another site? Is this something both websites have to add into their code? How does this work?

Comment: can you give an example? of your intended ref.

Comment: Could be set by the referring site, or the request could be captured and re-routed with the `ref` parameter on the receiving site, could be done with JavaScript ... this is waaay too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Both sites implement code for it so site A can track if someone clicks a link to them from site B.

**Option 2**

Site A implements a catch all address that gets linked to, then gets the referrer from the request header, appends this to the url and redirects to the page the user wanted to go to originally (or uses the referrer directly without showing it in the URL)

Comment: What if manually I change the text in ref? Will the other website be able to see the string I wrote?